# I can't see my react page after add Routes

Tags: reactjs

routes file

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import Filter from './pages/filter';

export const Routers = () => {
    return (
        <Router>
            <Routes>
                <Route exact path='/index' Component={Filter}>
                </Route>
            </Routes>
        </Router>
    )
}
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import { Route, BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Routers } from './Route';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Routers>
      <Route>
        <App />
      </Route>
    </Routers>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

I don't know why but I don't see anything, just a white page. I followed a procedure and I've installed npm install react-router-dom

Comment: In `index.js` you have `<Router>`. Is this a typo or copy/paste issue or is it actually `<Router>`. It should be `<Routes>`

Comment: If i change it in routes I receive an error [App] is not a <Route> component. All component children of <Routes> must be a <Route> or <React.Fragment>

Comment: You imported the wrong `<Routes>`! There is one in `react-router-dom` and the one your created has the same name. I would advise to rename your component and make sure you import your component correctly then

Comment: @devnull69 Ive imported  Routes from 'react-router-dom';

Comment: And that's the problem. What do you want to do with your _own_ `Routes` component you created in your first code sample? This is the one you actually _wanted_ to import, isn't it?

Comment: now I receive  A <Route> is only ever to be used as the child of <Routes> element, never rendered directly. Please wrap your <Route> in a <Routes>.

Comment: I updated my code now I see just a white page

Comment: Does your filter component has an `<Outlet />` anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to change tha path to Route exact path='/' ?
this should work if your url of application is something like this "http://localhost:3000/"

Comment: Yes I tried but nothing changes

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).